# [Android]How to disable page horizontal move along drag in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, swipe

I have a ViewPager with a FragmentPageAdapter set for it.
And the ViewPager is show some simple fragment.
I am able to use ViewPager for swipe between fragments.

However, I don't like the scrolling effect of ViewPager that showing partial content of next fragment while swiping/dragging current fragment.

Instead, I would like to switch to next fragment at instant with swipe(but without scrolling effect) and show fragment immediately.

How can I do such thing(must use ViewPagger)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own ["SwipeDetector"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection) and use `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index, false)` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int,%20boolean%29) (second parameter indicates whether to enable animation or not).